# How can I make my horse less aggressive?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I encounter a wolf or a bandit, my horse insists on joining the fray.

I would much prefer if the horse just stayed out of it unless attacked, and/or ran away (and came back later).

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but if you do the dark brotherhood quest line in the mission after you kill the wife at her wedding , if you do the bonus you get the leader of the dark brotherhood's horse which is invincible so it could actually help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want a mod like [Cowardly Horses](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1522/?).  There are many such mods on Nexus mods.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason my googling did not reveal anything.

Comment: You can also set the horse's aggression level via console. But the mod path is usually a good idea overall.